# Apache common-email lib - TLS shows warning

Tags: java, scala, email

I am using Apache common-email lib. And my SMTP server requires me to endable TLS protocol.

However, doing so gives me a warning that this particular method deprecated. Would someone please let me know an alternative to this?

```
import org.apache.commons.mail._
val commonsMail = new SimpleEmail().setMsg(mail.message)
commonsMail.setHostName("smtp.office365.com")
commonsMail.setSmtpPort(25)
commonsMail.setTLS(true) //This line shows warning.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since commons email 1.3, use [setStartTLSEnabled()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#setStartTLSEnabled-boolean-) instead

[Here is why it was deprecated if you're interested](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/EMAIL-105)